# Get Data from Controller to Javascript and Pass It Into Modal Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-3

please give me some advice so this problem can be solved. So, i have modal, javascript, and controller. The question is :How can i get data from controller in my javascript and then used it into modal in the form of table?

This is my javascript looks like :

```js
function view_detail(SalesConsID) {
  $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/onpartners/view_detail/')?>/" + SalesConsID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
          $('.modal-title').text('Invoice : ' + SalesConsID);

        }
```

This is my Controller looks like :

```
$data['data_details'] = $this->M_Onpart->showdetails($id);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Please guide, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: @charlietfl i cant return data that i got from controller and using it into ajax and my modal, return nothing when i used console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of echo use return .. Then on your ajax. Console.log (data)..  after returning you can use your data in on ajax.

//Do something like

let html;

```
$.each(data, function(i, val){    
 html += `<tr><td>${val.stockname}</td>
 <td>${val.qty}</td>
 </tr>
`;
 $('#modal-content table').append(html);
});
```

Similary, you can do this with other.

Comment: yes it work and i got the data array in my javascript function.. now how can i pass it into my modal as a table ? pls help

Comment: 0: {stockname: "JHWGDH2", Barcode: "8887707192674", stocktype: "PANTS", Qty: "2", Remaining: "2"}
1: {stockname: "DJWUDSH5", Barcode: "8887707192675", stocktype: "DRESS", Qty: "2", Remaining: "2"}

how can i use that result into my modal table bro ?

Comment: I have updated my answer make sure to upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: is #modal-content table target div in my modal ? can i use that as id in my table body ? cause i need table header as well.. will accept your answer after this question bro

Comment: yes.. you can add it any where. #modal-content is nothing but a targetted div. I'm targeting your table inside a div with id of modal-content

Comment: Thanks for your advice, keep helping & sharing in this comunity.